# many-to-many and one-to-many mapping in java springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have those 3 entities that I want to transform to tables with relations

------user------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name="lastActive")
    private String lastActive;
    @Column(name="createdDate")
    private String createdDate;
    @Column(name="isBlocked")
    private boolean isBlocked;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
    private Institution institution;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

-----role------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="role_Id")
    private int roleId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable
    private Set<User> users;

}
```

-----institution------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "institution")
public class Institution {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="institution_Id")
    private int institutionId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "institution", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> user;
    
}
```

But when I run my project as a java application, no tables are created in mySQL workbench  (the error occurred after adding he many-to-many annotation it was creating the tables before I add it).

Any ideas on why my code isn't working ?
And this is my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = pass123
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=9090
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@OneToMany does not create table.
@ManyToMany creates a table, you have to specify its details, like:

In user class:

```
 @ManyToMany
 @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") })
 private Set<Role> roles;
```

In role class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
private Set<User> users;
```

Comment: thank you that worked but im having a problem!
the user_has_role table created does not have any foreign keys.. idk why

Comment: It's happend with me too, unfortunely I don't know neither... On my search, I found the annotation @MapsId but I didn't test it. 

I've seen on that link: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

I set manually the foreign keys on my db.

Comment: i fixed it you should add  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
to your application.properties

Comment: That's great!!! I'm going to apply on my code. Thanks